# Using html helpers in Razor web helper with Telerik

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

I try to create an html helper with a control from Telerik but to do that, I must have this directive at the top of the file:

@using Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI

The problem is in html helper, when I type '@using' and then try to typed 'Telerik', visual studio tells me that the namespace don't exist even if I already use this directive in many other places in the same project.

[image]

As you can see with the words in red, Telerik namespace produce errors; 'Cannot resolve symbol ...

This is the same code in one of my EditorTemplates folder of the same project but in this case, without errors:

[image]

Is it because it's not possible to have control other than the MVC framework or I missed something?

Thank you.

EDIT:

After searching and with the help of Darin, I finally found the problem. You can look in the comments of Darin answer.

Also, this this my final code that works:

```
@using System.Web.Mvc
@using Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI

@helper IntegerTextBox(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper html, string id, int? value, bool enable = true)
{
   @(html.Telerik().IntegerTextBox()
        .Name(id)
        .InputHtmlAttributes(new {style = "width:200px"})
        .Spinners(false)
        .EmptyMessage("")
        .MaxValue(int.MinValue)
        .MaxValue(int.MaxValue)
        .Value(value)
        .Enable(enable)
        )
}
```

Like I said, you cannot use a @using directive to System.Web.Mvc to reduce the fully qualified type of the first parameter. I don't know why... 'HtmlHelper' looks like 'html helper' or '@helper' ... the word is in conflict with something in the framework of MVC? I don't know!? :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess that's due to the lousy Razor Intellisense support in Visual Studio. Your code should work fine when you run it. You could try reopening the view, restating VS, disable plugins and if it is your lucky day you might even get Intellisense working.

By the way, you could use the `<namespaces>` section of your `~/Views/web.config` (not to confuse with `~/web.config`) and add the `Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI` namespace. This will avoid you the need to add it to every single Razor view that needs it. Obviously for changes to take effect after modifying this file don't forget to reopen the razor page (as I already said Razor Intellisense sucks badly in VS).

Comment: Hi Darin, I do exactly what you said. I also crossed my fingers without luck. :( When I start the project, I have an error in the browser like when I really have errors in the helper page. In the using intellisense, I have absolutely all the components in reference of my project EXCEPT this dawn Telerik.

Comment: Ok, I figure out what's the problem. It's because I give the name 'Telerik' for my html helper page and this create a conflict. I just renamed my class and all is ok. Brain fart!!!

Comment: Just for the information, after using the new code a couple of minutes, I found another weird thing. I must have a parameter 'html' of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' and in this case, the parameter type must be fully qualified; you cannot add a @using directive to 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' to be able to define the parameter in a short form like this 'HtmlHelper html'. If you do that and try to compile the application, you will have an error.